# PHP - Obtain specific values within Mutidimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array as follows:

```
[STATUS] => Array
   (
             [Information] = A
             [More Info ] = B
   )
[GPU0] => Array
   (
             [GPU] => 0
             [INFO] => 100
   )
```

Looking to use PHP to show [INFO] results.  Right now I have something like this:

```
$array = print_r($result, true)."\n";
echo $array['GPU0']['GPU'];
```

My results are as follows:

```
Illegal string offset 'GPU0' in /var/www/somethinghere.php on line 117
```

Comment: What is `$result`, a string? Why would you use `print_r` to access the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$result` is an array, `$array` is a string that contains what `print_r` would have printed. You should do:

```
echo $result['GPU0']['GPU'];
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/lDpWWe)

Comment: Thank you, this returns the result of the array in its entirety, sorry if my question was unclear.  What I'm going for is to return the result of ['GPU'] which is "0"

Comment: It should just print the contents of that one element, not the whole array.

Comment: See the demo I just created.